# Show contextmenu in cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, clone

I created a `contextmenu` to show against specific classes, but when I cloned an element with that class the `contextmenu` is not shown.

Show the ContextMenu:

```
// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(".ui-editable").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
  // Avoid the real one
  event.preventDefault();
  //Save the selected and the parent element 
  selected_area = $(this);
  parent_area = $(this).parent();    

  $(this).addClass('selected-menu')// Show contextmenu

  $("#editContextMenu").finish().toggle(100).

  // In the right position (the mouse)
  css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
  });

});
```

Clone the element:

```
function cloneBlock() {

  $(selected_area).clone().appendTo(parent_area);

}
```

The full example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/marana12/xsd2n9uo/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) has an additional argument

> **withDataAndEvents** (default: false)
> Type: Boolean
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements.

So you can update your code to:

```
$(selected_area).clone(true).appendTo(parent_area);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/95rLne7m/

---

The alternative is to use event delegation, so it doesn't matter when/how the HTML is created, change:

```
$(".ui-editable").bind("contextmenu", function...
```

to

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".ui-editable", function...
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/95rLne7m/1/